# h3 Implicit event handler conversion is deprecated. Use `eventHandler()` or `fromNodeMiddleware()` to define event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, vite

I'm trying to get SSR working with vite and having a bad time. The server.js runs (thought it does have a warning), but when I try to go to the server localcally, the browser just hangs.

I'm using h3, sirv and listhen in the server.js file. Also I'm using react-router-dom 6.4.

If I put a console.log("here"), before the await it gets hit. So it looks like it is awaiting a http request, but when the browser goes to localhost:3001 the browser just keeps spinning and doesn't load like its waiting for a response.

What am I doing wrong!? I suspect something in the server.js.

I've got the following server.js

```
// app/server.js

import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

import { createApp } from "h3";
import { createServer as createViteServer } from "vite";
import { listen } from "listhen";
import sirv from "sirv";

const DEV_ENV = "development";

const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = createApp();
  let vite;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === DEV_ENV) {
    vite = await createViteServer({
      server: { middlewareMode: true },
      appType: "custom",
    });

    app.use(vite.middlewares);
  } else {
    app.use(sirv("dist/client", {
        gzip: true,
      })
    );
  }

  app.use("*", async (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl;
    let template, render;

    try {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === DEV_ENV) {
        template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./index.html"), "utf-8");

        template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);

        render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule("/src/entry-server.jsx")).render;
      } else {
        template = fs.readFileSync(
          path.resolve("dist/client/index.html"),
          "utf-8"
        );
        render = (await import("./dist/server/entry-server.js")).render;
      }

      const appHtml = await render({ path: url });

      const html = template.replace(`<!--ssr-outlet-->`, appHtml);

      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html").end(html);
    } catch (error) {
      vite.ssrFixStacktrace(error);
      next(error);
    }
  });

  return { app };
};

bootstrap()
  .then(async ({ app }) => {
    console.log("here")
    await listen(app, { port: 3001 });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

And i'm running it with

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run serve
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "vite build --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.jsx --outDir dist/server",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "h3": "^1.6.6",
    "listhen": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "sirv": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

And my index.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"><!--ssr-outlet--></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/entry-client.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

entry-client.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Router from "./router.jsx";
import store from "./store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById("app"),
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

entry-server.jsx:

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";

import Router from "./router";

export const render = ({ path }) => {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={path}>
      <Router />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
};
```

and finally, the output of the terminal when I run npm run dev

╰

```
 npm run dev                                                                ✘  10133   13:19    12.06.23

> frontend@0.0.0 dev
> NODE_ENV=development node server

[h3] Implicit event handler conversion is deprecated. Use `eventHandler()` or `fromNodeMiddleware()` to define event handlers.
     Handler: function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
[h3] Implicit event handler conversion is deprecated. Use `eventHandler()` or `fromNodeMiddleware()` to define event handlers.
     Route: *
     Handler: async (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl;
    let template, render;

    try {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === DEV_ENV) {
        template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./index.html"), "utf-8");

        template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);

        render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule("/src/entry-server.jsx")).render;
      } else {
        template = fs.readFileSync(
          path.resolve("dist/client/index.html"),
          "utf-8"
        );
        render = (await import("./dist/server/entry-server.js")).render;
      }

      const appHtml = await render({ path: url });

      const html = template.replace(`<!--ssr-outlet-->`, appHtml);

      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html").end(html);
    } catch (error) {
      vite.ssrFixStacktrace(error);
      next(error);
    }
  }

  > Local:    http://localhost:3001/
  > Network:  http://192.168.0.20:3001/
```

[image: folder structure]

Sorry I know that is a lot of code. But I can't figure out what would be causing it to hang like that. The browser doesn't load the page, and the browser just keeps 'spinning' like its waiting for a response that never comes.

Could it be the asynchronous stuff in the server.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was all in the error message. I just didn't understand it.

Had to wrap the (req, res, next) functions in fromNodeMiddleware

Updated server.js file is here:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import path from 'path'

import { createApp, fromNodeMiddleware, toNodeListener } from 'h3'
import { createServer as createViteServer } from 'vite'
import { listen } from 'listhen'
import sirv from 'sirv'

const DEV_ENV = 'development'

const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = createApp()
  let vite

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === DEV_ENV) {
    vite = await createViteServer({
      server: { middlewareMode: true },
      appType: 'custom'
    })

    app.use(fromNodeMiddleware(vite.middlewares))
  } else {
    app.use(
      fromNodeMiddleware(sirv('dist/client', {
        gzip: true
      }))
    )
  }

  app.use(
    '*',
    fromNodeMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
      const url = req.originalUrl
      let template, render

      try {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === DEV_ENV) {
          template = await fs.readFile(path.resolve('./index.html'), 'utf-8')

          template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)

          render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule('/src/entry-server.jsx')).render
        } else {
          template = await fs.readFile(
            path.resolve('dist/client/index.html'),
            'utf-8'
          )
          render = (await import('./dist/server/entry-server.js')).render
        }

        const appHtml = await render({ path: url })
        const html = template.replace('<!--ssr-outlet-->', appHtml)

        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html').end(html)
      } catch (error) {
        vite.ssrFixStacktrace(error)
        next(error)
      }
    })
  )

  return { app }
}

bootstrap()
  .then(async ({ app }) => {
    await listen(toNodeListener(app), { port: 3001 })
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```